# VueJs цикл со счетчиком

Tags: vue.js, for

Мне нужно сделать простой цикл со счетчиком в шаблоне. Аналог такого:

```
for(var i = 3; i <= 8; i++)
```

Не могу найти как это делается на Vue/

Сейчас у меня сделано так:

`v-for="n in 10"`

Но это не подходит т.к. отсчет всегда начинается с единицы

Comment: В смысле? Вот так и делается. Что надо-то? Цель какая?

Comment: Дополнил вопрос

Comment: То есть в шаблоне нужно прорисовать несколько компонентов, беря данные из массива?

Comment: Примерно. Только данные не берутся из массива. Суть в том, что мне необходимо стартовать цикл от определенного числа

Comment: Добавил ответ. Скажи, получилось? У меня рисует как надо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все оказалось проще:

Цикл от 6 до 12:

```
<h1 v-for="n in (12 - 5)">{{ 5 + n }}</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно отрисовать несколько компонентов, то так попробуй

`<h1 v-for="(n, index) in 10" :key="index">{{ index + 5 }}</h1>`

В этом варианте отрисуется с 5 по 15 внутри тэга. Если надо с нуля, то просто `index` юзай. С 0 тогда будет.

Comment: Не совсем. По задумке должно произойти 5 итераций (от 5 до 10)

Comment: Так. Давай подробнее. Что ты хочешь сделать и для чего?